# How to delete rows with loop oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_job_procedure
IS
    -- zamowienia cursor
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT * from test t FOR UPDATE t.kol1;
    crow   c1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
    open c1;
    loop
        fetch c1 into crow;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        DELETE FROM test where current of c1;
    end loop;
    COMMIT;
    close c1;
END;
```

How should I do it? I what delete rows from test table where id>100;

I WANT SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

1. GET z.id_zlecenia from zlecenia where WHERE z.DATA_PRZYJECIA_ZLECENIA < SYSTIMESTAMP - 10;
2. DELETE FROM ZLECENIA z WHERE z.id_zlecenia (one FROM GET).
3. DELETE FROM ZLECENIA2 WHERE z.id_zlecenia (one from GET).

Comment: Are you are aware that you don't need a loop at all to do what you want?

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: also I'll never recommend loop in sql. This is some kind of last resort thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two delete statement as follows:

```
Delete from zlecenia2
Where id_zlecenia IN
(Select z.id_zlecenia 
   from zlecenia z
  WHERE z.DATA_PRZYJECIA_ZLECENIA < SYSTIMESTAMP - 10);

Delete from zlecenia
WHERE DATA_PRZYJECIA_ZLECENIA < SYSTIMESTAMP - 10;
```